# How do I remove Ubuntu from a dual boot without a Windows or Ubuntu CD?

Tags: uninstall

I am running a Dell E6400 laptop computer, with limited hard drive space and need to recover the hard drive space used by Ubuntu.

At a later date I wish to install Ubuntu to an external hard drive so that I may continue to utilize the versatility of Ubuntu.

How do  I remove Ubuntu and recover its partition space?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Is that an real dual boot or Wubi installation of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Warning: This may not work with UEFI / EFI / Windows 8 or Wubi setups.

1. Run these command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install lilo
   sudo lilo -M /dev/DEVICE
   ```

   (Replace `/dev/DEVICE` with the path to your disk with Ubuntu, **without a number**, e.g.: `/dev/sda`)
2. Reboot. At this point, it should boot straight into Windows.
3. From Window's Disk Management program, delete the Ubuntu partitions. (they should be shown as partitioned "Free Space".)

Comment: Sorry, it may work, but how does install LInux LOader help? Does it replace Grub or something?

Comment: @wilf: Normally, Ubuntu uses GRUB. GRUB requires supporting files on a Ubuntu partition. LILO doesn't need any extra files and can sit happily in the MBR chainloading Windows without anything extra needed. Yes, it does replace GRUB.

Comment: Tiny bit weird, understandable + useful...

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have your windows boot disk or pendrive you can download the exact same version of windows (for eg. If you are using win8.1 there are different version like single language and win8.1core etc. ) select it and download that (preferably from microsoft’s own website”It’s free”) and take any pendrive and make it bootable using the downloaded iso file image.Then use it as installation disk!!Worked for me!! (I didnt have my windows installation disk!!) Hope it helps!!